# Python code to print negotiated tls version at both client and server side during TLS communication

Tags: python, ssl, client, cherrypy, urllib3

We can configure supported range of tls versions(at server). During the client to server TLS communication I need to print negotiated TLS version of communication, print this information both at the server and client side logs.

Here I have tried to give sample code(not a running code) from the client side, urllib3 is the client side module used to trigger URL corresponding to server.
Supports both TLSv1_2 and TLSv1_3 versions.

```
self.__connection = ProxyManager(proxy_url=proxy_url,
                                         proxy_headers=self.__get_proxy_headers(),
                                         proxy_ssl_context=self.__get_proxy_ssl_context(proxy_url),
                                         cert_file=cert_file,
                                         key_file=cert_key,
                                         key_password=key_pwd,
                                         cert_reqs=cert_reqs,
                                         ca_certs=ca_cert,
                                         timeout=self._get_timeout(connect_timeout=self.__connect_timeout,
                                                                   read_timeout=self.__read_timeout),
                                         ssl_context=self.__get_ssl_context(),
                                         retries=False)
                                         
def __get_ssl_context():
    ssl_context = create_urllib3_context(ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT,
                                     
    ciphers=constants.SSL_TLS_CIPHER_SUITE)
    ssl_context.set_ecdh_curve(constants.SSL_TLS_CURVE)
    ssl_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
    return ssl_context
```

Here is the server side code where SSL context is created and assigned to cherrypy server.

```
cheroot.server.ssl_adapters['ssl-password-adapter'] = SSLPasswordAdapter

class SSLPasswordAdapter(BuiltinSSLAdapter):
   def __init__(self, certificate, private_key, certificate_chain=None, ciphers=None):

    self.certificate = certificate
    self.private_key = private_key
    self.certificate_chain = certificate_chain
    self.ciphers = ciphers

    self.context = ssl.create_default_context(
        purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH,
        cafile=certificate_chain,
    )

    self.context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
    self.context.load_cert_chain(certificate, private_key, self._password)
    
    if self.ciphers is not None:
        self.context.set_ciphers(ciphers)
    else:
        self.context.set_ciphers(constants.SSL_TLS_CIPHER_SUITE)
        self.context.set_ecdh_curve(constants.SSL_TLS_CURVE)
```

Now, expectation is when server URL is triggered from the client side using urllib3 and it reaches the server side, negotiated TLS version has to be printed on both client and server side.

Comment: For a bit of background -- is there a framework used on the server side? Without a framework I would be inclined to suggest using `SSLSocket.version()`, but I can't say the same if the socket layer is not directly used.

Comment: @mcendu cherrypy webserver framework is used at the server side.

Comment: See [SSLSocket.version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.version). How this can be accessed from your code is unclear though, since you did not provide any code. If you don't have direct access to the socket in server and/or client the information might be exposed in some other way - but again: no better help without code details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich added sample code for refrence.